# POST data via CustomTab or Chrome

Tags: java, android, android-volley, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I want send POST HTTP request via CustomTab or Chrome then show page finally. I many research but no way for it.
is there a way?
can send POST request via Volley then show response in browser finally?

Comment: no way really? :(

Comment: Even on desktop, there's no way to day this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a workaround for that.

Careful, is a dirty one ;)

**Steps:**

- you need to create an html file with a form inside it
- add input fields to it corresponding to the values you need to pass to your url
- add this file to your asset folder
- on android code:

  - read the content of the file
  - save the content to the external cache directory
  - **>>THIS STEP IS FUNDAMENTAL<<** from now on follow these instructions (@Skotos's answer on how to open a local html with a custom tab intent https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078339/2124387)

**Example:**

this is my html file called `form_template.html` in the assets folder:

```
    <html>
        <script>
            function submitForm() {
                document.getElementById("form").submit()
            }
        </script>

        <body onload="submitForm()">
            <form id="form" action="{{url}}" method="{{method}}" enctype="{{enctype}}">
                {{fields}}
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

end this is how i pass dynamically url and values to it

```
    Map<String, String> values = ImmutableMap.of(
        "fooKey", "fooValue", // whatever you
        "barKey", "barValue"  // need here
    );

    try {
        File redirect = new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir(), "redirect.html");

        // To get string from input stream look at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110044/2124387
        String templateString = getStringFromInputStream(activity.getAssets().open("form_template.html"));

        List<String> inputFields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : values.keySet()) {
            inputFields.add(String.format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" />", key, values.get(key)));
        }

        templateString = templateString.replace("{{url}}", url);
        templateString = templateString.replace("{{method}}", method); // eg. "POST"
        templateString = templateString.replace("{{enctype}}", encodeType); // eg. "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        templateString = templateString.replace("{{fields}}", StringUtil.join("\n", inputFields));

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(redirect);
        fileOutputStream.write(templateString.getBytes());
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.ApplicationId + ".provider", redirect);
        new Handler().postDelayed(redirect::delete, 5000);

        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION))
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, packageName, url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.. although there was 1sec lag due to form submission, apart from that it worked great. Also just make sure that {{fields}} should be replaced by the <input/> tags with proper id, name and value